# What is this javascript idiom?

Tags: javascript, broccolijs

I was going through broccoli plugins and I see this line a lot. What is it used for?

```
function MyCompiler (arg1, arg2, ...) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyCompiler)) return new MyCompiler(arg1, arg2, ...);
  ...
};
```

Comment: it guards against forgetting "new " when constructing an instance, turning a direct call into a "new " call (which alters _this_ from global to the instance itself).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is so that you can use it with or without the `new` keyword.

E.g.:

```
var comp = new MyCompiler();
```

or:

```
var comp = MyCompiler();
```

If you call it as a function, it will call itself with the `new` keyword and return the instance.